# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to get record from my db where hidden=false and id is got in browser. Please see my code and fix for me, thanks so much (I searched but can not fix my error). 
My action:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id = 0)
    {
        var item = db.Destinations.Where(i=>i.Hidden==false && i.Id==id);

        if (item==null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

My View:

```
@model vtt.Models.Destination
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
    }
    <div class="white">
     <h1>@Model.Name</h1>
     @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
    </div>
```

And Error:

```
 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
        'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[vtt.Models.Destination]', but this dictionary
        requires a model item of type 'vtt.Models.Destination'.
```

Comment: isn't the error message self explanatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're trying to pass in a model which is a *query*, whereas your view is expecting a *single* model object. Currently your check for nullity is pointless, too - the result of `Where` is never `null`... it's just a query.

Instead, you should use `SingleOrDefault`, which *executes the query, getting a single value:

```
var item = db.Destinations.SingleOrDefault(i => !i.Hidden && i.Id == id);
```

Now the check for nullity will be useful (because `SingleOrDefault` will return `null` if there are no results) and the type will be correct for the view.

Comment: Thank Jon Skeet a lot, That's all for me.